No way to show() DialogFragment without calling deprecated setTargetFragment()
I have been using the following code to display a custom dialog:
public void onDisplayPreferenceDialog(@NonNull Preference preference) {
    dialogFragment = SomeCustomDialog.newInstance(preference.getKey());
    dialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
    dialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
            "androidx.preference.PreferenceFragment.DIALOG");
}

This is working fine, but I have been trying to work out a different way to show the Dialog without using the deprecated setTargetFragment() method.
According to the documentation, theoretically I should be able to show the dialog by simply calling:
new SomeCustomDialog().show(
        getChildFragmentManager(), "androidx.preference.PreferenceFragment.DIALOG");

However, doing that results in an exception:
Target fragment must implement TargetFragment interface

Am I missing something? Or should I just continue using the setTargetFragment() method?
